# CollectionViewCell sends previous image

Tags: swift, collectionview

**I'm sending image selected from collectionView. And the problem is that the application always sends previously selected image. What is wrong with indexPath?**

**Here's the didSelectItemAt function:**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    options.isSynchronous = true

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item), targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { image, error in   
        guard let image = image else { return }          
        self.image = image

    })

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue099", sender: self)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/1616964-requestimage)

> By default, this method executes asynchronously. If you call it from a background thread you may change the isSynchronous property of the options parameter to true to block the calling thread until either the requested image is ready or an error occurs, at which time Photos calls your result handler.

So

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue099", sender: self)
```

runs before fetching the image which cause it to pass the old image so either `true` the `isSynchronous` or put the segue inside the callback

Comment: I tried isSynchronous = false and I'm still getting previous image. I don't know how to use callbacks in this function. But, maybe I will figure it out later.

Comment: make it **true** as in answer

Comment: Yeah, but it's true as in my question. And it's not working.